# Substitute substrings as a whole

Tags: replace, julia, string-matching

I have a string, like "31.5*q*L^2+831.5*M". I want to have the string transformed into "\num{31.5}*q*L^2+\num{831.5}*M".

In Julia, I already tried:

```
str="31.5*q*L^2+831.5*M";
temp1=matchall(r"(\d*\.?\d+|\d+\.?\d*)",str);
str1=replace(str,temp1[1],"\\num\{"*temp1[1]*"\}");
```

Then I got unexpected result: "\num{31.5}*q*L^2+8\num{31.5}*M".

What is the solution for this problem?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`replace(str,r"(\d*\.?\d+|\d+\.?\d*)",s->"\\num\{$s\}")` may be the required solution. Though it does replace them exponent 2 in `L^2` as well. To avoid this replacement, changing the pattern is required.

For more information try `?replace` on the Julia prompt (REPL). The specific method above uses a `Function` type for the `r` parameter.

It may be that `replace` isn't flexible enough for a simple solution and then a loop can go over each number and replace it individually. This is more tricky. Try the following code:

```
str="31.5*q*L^2+831.5*M"

# The SLOW but more FLEXIBLE way
str1 = ""
lastpos = 1
for m in eachmatch(r"(?:^|[\+\*])(\d*\.?\d+|\d+\.?\d*)",str,false)
    str1=str1*str[lastpos:m.captures[1].offset]*"\\num\{"*m.captures[1]*"\}"
    lastpos = m.captures[1].endof+m.captures[1].offset+1 
end
str1 = str1*str[lastpos:end]
```

The above uses `eachmatch` and the internals of `SubString` type. Sometimes getting into details is unavoidable.

Comment: The regular expression may need a bit more fiddling to get at just the required set of replacement matches.

Comment: Great. Your solution saves me hours of coding. Further improvement will deal the case when str is, for example, "31.5*q*L^2+831.5*M-8.1/EI+8.1/(3*a^2+     1.5)" [blank spaces added before 1.5 intentionally]. It is as follows: for m in eachmatch(r"(?:^|[\+\*\-\(\ ])(\d*\.?\d+|\d+\.?\d*)",str,false)